# How to go to the immediate parent of a project

Tags: rest, versionone

I am working on VerionOne API,and have reached to a point wherein I can limit the records returned.What I am actually trying to do is ,given a Scope,how will you navigate tot eh parent of the scope? if they are in a hierarchy at all?

Following is the endpoint I am using:

https:///rest-1.v1/Data/Scope?sel=Name,Custom_Type,Parent&where=Custom_Type.Name=%27PSI%27&page=10,0&xsl=custom/table.xsl

result:

Oid Name    Custom_Type Parent  Custom_Type.Name    Parent.Name
Scope:1020  SCADA/EMS - old schedule    Custom_Type:8704
Scope:177198
PSI SCADA / EMS Releases

What I want is, I want to use parentAndUp(or any other way) to move to the immediate parent of the scope,with the name coming out form the output,for example in the above result it would be: "SCADA / EMS Releases"
I infact tried to do this too:

https:///rest-1.v1/Data/Scope?sel=Name,Custom_Type,Parent&where=Custom_Type.Name=%27PSI%27&page=10,0&Scope.ParentAndUp.Name=%27SCADA%20/%20EMS%20Releases%27&xsl=custom/table.xsl

but the above query still returns me 10 records,it should only return me 1 record,is this assumption correct?

I want to know the exact parameter I should be using so that the endpoint gives me directly to the parent without having me to provide the parent's name explicitly.Is this even possible?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: well I think so I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have already discovered, most assets within VersionOne have a `Parent` attribute that you can use to get the OID of the asset's parent.

Here's the meta query that you can use to find all the attributes and relations for the Scope (project) asset:

```
http://{server}/{instance}/meta.v1/Scope?xsl=api.xsl
```